# Automatically sum numeric columns and print total

Tags: language-agnostic, awk, code-golf

Given the output of `git ... --stat`:

```
 3 files changed, 72 insertions(+), 21 deletions(-)
 3 files changed, 27 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
 4 files changed, 164 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 9 files changed, 395 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 1 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
 2 files changed, 57 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 10 files changed, 189 insertions(+), 230 deletions(-)
 3 files changed, 111 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 8 files changed, 61 insertions(+), 80 deletions(-)
```

I wanted to produce the sum of the numeric columns but preserve the formatting of the line.  **In the interest of generality, I produced this awk script that automatically sums any numeric columns and produces a summary line:**

```
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i + 0 != 0) {
            numeric[i] = 1;
            total[i] += $i;
        }
    }
}
END {
    # re-use non-numeric columns of last line
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if (numeric[i])
            $i = total[i]
    }
    print
}
```

Yielding:

```
 44 files changed, 1080 insertions(+), 338 deletions(-)
```

Awk has several features that simplify the problem, like automatic string->number conversion, all arrays as associative arrays, and the ability to overwrite auto-split positional parameters and then print the equivalent lines.

Is there a better language for this hack?

Comment: This did turn into an interesting code-golf question, but I feel I should ask what you're trying to accomplish here. Are your "X files changed" lines coming from git log? If so, simply summing the number of files changed isn't accurate if you've changed the same file in multiple changesets. If you want to find what happened between two points, you might want git diff --stat <start> <end>.

Comment: @Mike:  The "X files changed" is definitely wrong, the other totals are close to what I wanted.  The revisions in question aren't perfectly sequential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Perl - 47 char

Inspired by ChristopheD's awk solution. Used with the `-an` command-line switch. 43 chars + 4 chars for the command-line switch:

```
$i-=@a=map{($b[$i++]+=$_)||$_}@F}{print"@a"
```

I can get it to 45 (41 + `-ap` switch) with a little bit of cheating:

```
$i=0;$_="Ctrl-M@{[map{($b[$i++]+=$_)||$_}@F]}"
```

Older, hash-based 66 char solution:

```
@a=(),s#(\d+)(\D+)#$b{$a[@a]=$2}+=$1#gefor<>;print map$b{$_}.$_,@a
```

Comment: I haven't worked out quite how it works yet but I note that the true input happens to start with a space (direct from git) and this inserts a bogus "0" column:  `0 44 files changed, 1080 insertions(+), 338 deletions(-)`

Comment: @Ben Jackson - that's a bummer - I'll see what I can do

Comment: Do I read 'gefor' correctly as `s///ge for`?  I had no idea perl would find a token like that at the end of valid substitution options!

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 101 chars

```
import sys
print" ".join(`sum(map(int,x))`if"A">x[0]else x[0]for x in zip(*map(str.split,sys.stdin)))'
```

Using reduce is longer at 126 chars

```
import sys
print" ".join(reduce(lambda X,Y:[str(int(x)+int(y))if"A">x[0]else x for x,y in zip(X,Y)],map(str.split,sys.stdin)))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby — 87

```
puts ' '+[*$<].map(&:split).inject{|i,j|[0,3,5].map{|k|i[k]=i[k].to_i+j[k].to_i};i}*' '
```

Comment: Wow. +1 for `[*$<]` which is awesome *and* golfy. I guess that works because `$<` defines a `.to_a` method that reads everything?  And because splat apparently calls `.to_a`? (I'm not sure this response actually qualifies because you hardwired the columns, but I still like it.)

Comment: hard-coded column numbers? ewww! while you are at it, why not abbreviate to `puts '44 files changed, 1080 insertions(+), 338 deletions(-)'`

Comment: My original does auto-detect the numeric columns.  I was thinking of making a general tool I could keep in my bin directory to sum columns of any output.

Answer (score 2):

### AWK - 63 characters

(in a bash script, $1 is the filename provided as command line argument):

```
awk -F' ' '{x+=$1;y+=$4;z+=$6}END{print x,$2,$3,y,$5,z,$7}' $1
```

One could of course also pipe the input in (would save another 3 characters when allowed).

Comment: I think the "program" is the thing between the "{ .. }" so 47 chars on my count. Well done!

Comment: The initial space is lacking in the output, though.

Comment: This is not flexible, the columns are HARDCODED

Comment: The question is well too under-specified to provide a generic, flexible solution (without taking a lot of assumptions about the format) imho...

Comment: @Nas well ... a column is a column ... a thing between two voids ... how do you softcode it? :)

Comment: @ChristopheD: the sample implementation clarifies the desired outcome. I dont think it's a big stretch to think of "if this column is a number, total it; otherwise keep the (first|last|min|max|random|unchanged) value". You can vary in your choice of handling non-numeric columns indeed... but there result with the sample data will be the same... and there will be "least surprise" with different inputs

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not challenging or difficult... it is "cute" though.

Here is solution in Python:

```
import sys
r = []
for s in sys.stdin:
    r = map(lambda x,y:(x or 0)+int(y) if y.isdigit() else y, r, s.split())
print ' '.join(map(str, r))
```

What does it do... it keeps tally in `r` while proceeding line by line. Splits the line, then for each element of the list, if it is a number, adds it to the tally or keeps it as string. At the end they all get re-mapped to string and merged with spaces in between to be printed.

Alternative, more "algebraic" implementation, if we did not care about reading all input at once:

```
import sys

def totalize(l):
    try:    r = str(sum(map(int,l)))
    except: r = l[-1]
    return r

print ' '.join(map(totalize, zip(*map(str.split, sys.stdin))))
```

What does this one do? `totalize()` takes a list of strings and tries to calculate sum of the numbers; if that fails, it simply returns the last one. `zip()` is fed with a matrix that is list of rows, each of them being list of column items in the row - zip transposes the matrix so it turns into list of column items and then `totalize` is invoked on each column and the results are joined as before.

Comment: Only objection:  Awk version handles floats as well.  Perhaps not a difficult problem, but I did learn something about python I didn't know!

Comment: @Ben Jackson: use the 2nd solution, substitute `float` for `int` there.

Answer (score 1):

At the expense of making your code slightly longer, I moved the main parsing into the `BEGIN` clause so the main clause is only processing numeric fields. For a slightly larger input file, I was able to measure a significant improvement in speed.

```
BEGIN {
    getline
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        # need to test for 0, too, in this version
        if ($i == 0 || $i + 0 != 0) {
            numeric[i] = 1;
            total[i] = $i;
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i in numeric) total[i] += $i
}
END {
    # re-use non-numeric columns of last line
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if (numeric[i])
            $i = total[i]
    }
    print
}
```

I made a test file using your data and doing `paste file file file ...` and `cat file file file ...` so that the result had 147 fields and 1960 records. My version took about 1/4 as long as yours. On the original data, the difference was not measurable.

Comment: Somehow I never in all my awk thought of `BEGIN { getline ... }` which is cleaner than tricks like `init == 0 { ...; init = 1}`.  I do like the ability of the original to ignore headers, though.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (Rhino) - <s>183</s> <s>154</s> 139 bytes

Golfed:

```
x=[n=0,0,0];s=[];readFile('/dev/stdin').replace(/(\d+)(\D+)/g,function(a,b,c){x[n]+=+b;s[n++]=c;n%=3});print(x[0]+s[0]+x[1]+s[1]+x[2]+s[2])
```

Readable-ish:

```
x=[n=0,0,0];
s=[];

readFile('/dev/stdin').replace(/(\d+)(\D+)/g,function(a,b,c){
    x[n]+=+b;
    s[n++]=c;
    n%=3
});

print(x[0]+s[0]+x[1]+s[1]+x[2]+s[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP <strike>152</strike> 130 Chars

Input:

```
$i = "
3 files changed, 72 insertions(+), 21 deletions(-) 
3 files changed, 27 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-) 
4 files changed, 164 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-) 
9 files changed, 395 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-) 
1 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-) 
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-) 
2 files changed, 57 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-) 
10 files changed, 189 insertions(+), 230 deletions(-) 
3 files changed, 111 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-) 
8 files changed, 61 insertions(+), 80 deletions(-)";
```

Code:

```
$a = explode(" ", $i);

foreach($a as $k => $v){
    if($k % 7 == 0)
        $x += $v;

    if(3-$k % 7 == 0)
        $y += $v;

    if(5-$k % 7 == 0)
        $z += $v;   

}

echo "$x $a[1] $a[2] $y $a[4] $z $a[6]";
```

Output:

```
44 files changed, 1080 insertions(+), 338 deletions(-)
```

Note: explode() will require that there is a space char before the new line.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell - <strike>151</strike> 135 bytes

```
import Char
c a b|all isDigit(a++b)=show$read a+read b|True=a
main=interact$unwords.foldl1(zipWith c).map words.filter(not.null).lines
```

... but I'm sure it can be done better/smaller.

Comment: Just from my mind: I guess it's shorter to hard-code the position of columns and convert with read.

Answer (score 0):

**Lua, 140 bytes**

I know Lua isn't the best golfing language, but compared by the size of the runtimes, it does pretty well I think.

```
f,i,d,s=0,0,0,io.read"*a"for g,a,j,b,e,c in s:gmatch("(%d+)(.-)(%d+)(.-)(%d+)(.-)")do f,i,d=f+g,i+j,d+e end print(table.concat{f,a,i,b,d,c})
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <s>176 166 164 159 158</s> 153

```
for($a=-1;$a<count($l=explode("
",$i));$r=explode(" ",$l[++$a]))for($b=-1;$b<count($r);$c[++$b]=is_numeric($r[$b])?$c[$b]+$r[$b]:$r[$b]);echo join(" ",$c);
```

This would, however, require the whole input in *$i*... A variant with *$i* replaced with *$_POST["i"]* so it would be sent in a textarea... Has **162** chars:

```
for($a=-1;$a<count($l=explode("
",$_POST["i"]));$r=explode(" ",$l[$a++]))for($b=0;$b<count($r);$c[$b]=is_numeric($r[$b])?$c[$b]+$r[$b]:$r[$b])$b++;echo join(" ",$c);
```

This is a version with

### NO HARDCODED COLUMNS